# Some Windows10 Services have an extension - 11aeeb

Tags: services, windows-10

Curious if anyone knows anything about this. I noticed that a good dozen or more services on a Windows 10 PC have an series of numbers letters on them , 11aeeb. Anyone know what this means?

[image]

This is just a random selection of a few of them.

Comment: Is there some way to move this ?

Comment: You already posted the same question a short while ago.

Comment: Actually it was migrated, well I couldn't migrate so I posted here as someone suggested on previous post. The other post was flag for delete.